# parsing JSON and removing extraneous characters before adding to observable collection

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime, json.net

I am trying to GET JSON From a webservice , which i was able to figure out . BTW This was my JSON Data

```
 {
        "X-YZ-111/AB.CD": {
            "P1": "F",
            "P2": "43.46"
        },        

        "X-YZ-112/AB.CDRTE.D": {
            "P1": "F",
            "P2": "8.02"
        }
}
```

Now i am able trying to parse it into a collection,where each item has "X-YZ-111/AB.CD" as name property and P1 and P2 as other 2 properties ,which i will try to bind to a Tile in UI using CollectionViewSource later.

I am able to parse the JSON into my classes like this -

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(result);
var dict = jObj.Children()
           .Cast<JProperty>()
           .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, 
                         p => new Tuple<string, string>((string)p.Value["P1"], (string)p.Value["P2"]));
```

But  after parsing JSON and before adding the dict collection to observable collection i want to strip off all characters after "/" from Name Property.

So if it is `"X-YZ-112/AB.CDRTE.D"` , i want Name to be `"X-YZ-112"` and strip off `"AB.CDRTE.D"`. My Json data has 21 objects like this and all object's Name have this extraneous data. Is there anyway i can strip these chars before adding them to my observable collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a new dictionary?

```
var newDict = dict.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key.Split('/')[0], kv => kv.Value);
```

You also can do the same thing while parsing your json.

```
p => p.Name.Split('/')[0],
```